# HMAC_256 using Message Authentication Code on Solaris

Tags: bash, unix, base64, hmac, sha256

This problem is really leaving me astounded

1. Take a input file and create a HMAC_256 value from it using a private key
2. Base64 encode HMAC_256 hash

**Code**

```
#Create HMAC-SHA2 hash from shell parameter
filehash=`echo $1 | mac -a sha256_hmac -k test.key`
echo "HMAC_SHA256 hash : "$filehash
#Base64 encode filehash using openssl
filehash_64=`echo "$filehash" | /usr/sfw/bin//openssl enc -base64 | tr '\n' ' ' | cut -d " " -f2 `
echo "64 bit encoded hash : "$filehash_64
```

Using a test.key of

> Bob123

**Shell Input**

> Hello

**Shell Output**

```
SHA256 hash : 411796cfb1e6c30c1b39b589c79d6f8bf1fdde8d58fda4a6ec1e59538ecaa39a

64 bit encoded hash : ZWMxZTU5NTM4ZWNhYTM5YQo=
```

---

However if I go to these sites and do a HMAC_256 test they both generate a different hash

http://asecuritysite.com/encryption/hmac

http://jetcityorange.com/hmac/

They both Output a HMAC_256 hash of

> a30410f584726f32ba3e6e823bfdecbdf28448d64e4ab8f11f6a2e66818b50fe

Why are they generating a different hash? I am assuming they are correct as they both have the same.

- Does Solaris 10 have a bug with its MAC (Message Authentication Code)
  tool?
- Is it UTF8 or ASCII problem?
- Is it a server problem, Windows / Unix?

I don't understand why I am generating a different hash to them, even though I am using the same hashing algorithm and key.

Comment: For ``filehash=`echo $1 | mac -a sha256_hmac -k test.key` ``, `$1` probably should be quoted: `"$1"`. And follow [TheGreatContini](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24730605/445221)'s suggestion of using `-n`.

Comment: It is still different, I tried making an equivalent algorithm in Java and it makes a completely different Hash....

Comment: Perhaps posting that Java code would be helpful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll guess that the problem is newline characters.  The echo command puts a newline after "Hello", so if you don't want it, use "echo -n".  Also make sure that there is no newline character in your key file.